# How can I access a public Google Drive file by XHR (CORS) without authentication?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, google-drive-api, cors

I need a HTML page to access Google Drive files with `XMLHttpRequest` (XHR) in Javascript without authentication (so my users don't have to be signed in with or have a Google account). These files have permission "Anyone with link". Since these files are open for the world (having the link) I don't see why it would be a problem to allow Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) for them.

The `downloadUrl` requires authentication, so I guess that isn't a viable option. I have also looked at the `webViewLink`, which I guess requires the files to be "Public on the web" - turning up in search engines, etc, I guess. The is not a viable option for me either. I need the "Anyone with link" permission for these files. The most promising link is the `webContentLink`, which according to http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.se/2012/08/5-things-you-didnt-know-you-could-do.html allow public and unauthenticated access.

The problem I have with `webContentLink` is that it doesn't seem to be CORS friendly. My attempts with XHR in Chrome fail (quite silently). I don't add any headers.

My attempts with `curl` using `--header "Origin: http://www.hello.se"` and both with and without `--header "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET"` results in a `HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily` redirect to a short-lived content URL. The problem is that the redirect response has no signs of an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, which is needed to enable CORS.

Is there anything I can do differently to get this to work?

Otherwise Google SDK team, can you make make the `webContentLink` CORS friendly for public files (which don't need cookie authentication), please?

Comment: *"(...)Otherwise Google SDK team, can you make(...)"* I wouldn't be surprised if they did answer the question, but I think that expecting them to do so here is quite the assumption. Your suggestion will more probably be heard by them if you communicate it through Google's own channels.

Comment: @Renan I've seen developers from Google respond to and fix issues brought up on SO before. So it's not impossible :)

Comment: @Renan Looking at https://developers.google.com/drive/support, I seem to be in the right place.

Comment: @Anders did you resolve this? Can you post the code? I'm looking for the public URL that will work with CORS and will require no authorization. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

JSONP seems to be the only way to dynamically fetch google sheets from the client :

1) In Google Drive, Publish on the web the document & set sharing options to Public

2) Export your data in JSON format with a JSON type link, it will look like : "http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/YOUR_FILE_ID/od6/public/values?alt=json&callback=myCallback". You need to append &callback=myCallback to use JSONP. You can use jQuery to make your JSONP call.

3) Define a window.myCallback JS function to use the data

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the JS Google API client. It gets around the CORS restriction by downloading a proxy iframe.